# Commuting the variation and differentiation

Tags: field-theory

Suppose $\omega = (\omega^\alpha_\beta)$ is a matrix in the Lie algebra of the Lorentz group $so(1,3)$, and we vary a real scalar field $\phi$ on $4$-dimensional Minkowski spacetime by
$$\phi_s(x) = \phi(\exp(s\omega)x)$$
Then the variation is
$$\delta \phi(x) = \frac{d}{ds}\Bigr|_{s=0}\phi(\exp(s\omega)x) = \omega^\alpha_\beta x^\beta \partial_\alpha \phi(x)$$
It is often said that $\partial_\mu \delta \phi = \delta \partial_\mu \phi$. In this case we have
$$\delta \partial_\mu \phi = \omega^\alpha_\beta x^\beta \partial_\alpha \partial_\mu \phi$$
and
$$\partial_\mu \delta \phi = \partial_\mu (\omega^\alpha_\beta x^\beta \partial_\alpha \phi) = \partial_\mu(\omega^\alpha_\beta x^\beta) \partial_\alpha \phi + \omega^\alpha_\beta x^\beta \partial_\alpha \partial_\mu \phi$$
So it seems that to have the equality we'd need $\partial_\mu (\omega^\alpha_\beta x^\beta) = 0$, but to me it looks like $\partial_\mu (\omega^\alpha_\beta x^\beta) = \omega^\alpha_\mu$ which has no reason to be zero. What's going on here?

Comment: The transformation of $\partial_\mu\phi$ under a Lorentz transformation is not as you have written it. The simplest way to see this is to note that the derivative must also transform.

Comment: I don't see why. The formula $\delta \psi = \omega^\alpha_\beta x^\beta \partial_\alpha \psi$ is valid for any field $\psi$. In particular it should be valid for $\partial_\mu \phi$, no?

Comment: No. For one thing $\phi$ is a scalar under coordinate transformations while $\partial_\mu\phi$ is a vector. You even have written $x^\prime=\exp(s\omega)x$ for the coordinate transformation. Try doing it explicitly, keeping in mind that the derivative needs to transform too.

Comment: If you're looking for something more formal, observe that the symbol $\delta$ as you are using, and as you have defined it by your $s$ derivative is really defining the Lie derivative of $\phi$ along the flow generated by the action of the Lorentz transformation on the spacetime manifold. The Lie derivative of a vector and of a scalar are certainly not given by the same expression.

Comment: I see, the definition of $\delta$ is really much more subtle than it looks.